# html file input doesn't trigger on change event and disable file input control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a simple html form where I save product info and then refresh the screen with the saved product info. After that the user can upload a document. I have two questions here:

1. Until user has saved the product info, the upload button should be not clickable.
2. Once the product is saved and ID is generated, the file input button should be clickable and allow file upload.

I already tried to reset the form value like this from other posts:

```
$('#docUpload').closest('form').get(0).reset();
```

HTML

```
 <div class="input-group mb-3">                    
      <input type="file" id="docUpload" style="display:none"/> 
      <label for="docUpload" class="btn btn-info">Upload Doc</label>        
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#docUpload').on('click', function () {
    $('#docUpload').closest('form').get(0).reset();
    this.value = null;
});

$('#docUpload').on('change', function (e) {

    $('#docUpload').closest('form').get(0).reset();

    var files = $('#docUpload').get(0).files;

    var formData = new FormData();
    for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){

        formData.append('DocumentUpload', files[i]);
        formData.append('PId', $('#pId').val());
        formData.append('Name', 'abc');            
    }
        UploadFiles(formData);
    }); 

function UploadFiles(formData) {

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
        url: '/Some/UploadFile',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        }
    });

};
```

I can save the product info and reload the form from the ajax call back. 
I cannot get this file input to work consistently and I see DOMException in the console sometimes.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.
    at Object.t.messageJumpContext
```

The `onchange` event is not triggered consistently.

Answer (score 0):

On change event doesn't work on input type="file", Try using:

```
<script>
   $('#docUpload').on('keyup keydown blur keypress', function (e) {

      $('#docUpload').closest('form').get(0).reset();

      var files = $('#docUpload').get(0).files;

      var formData = new FormData();
    for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){

        formData.append('DocumentUpload', files[i]);
        formData.append('PId', $('#pId').val());
        formData.append('Name', 'abc');            
    }
        UploadFiles(formData);
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: It is not triggering the event with this change